# How to get closest input type text's value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am designing one table in html and it contains `time picker` in one td as start time and second time picker in second td as end time in one tr. I want to take both values (start time and end time) and want to calculate time difference and want to show in third td. But i am not able to get particular td's value to calculate difference.

```
  <table id="example1" class="machinetable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>

     <th>Sr. no.</th>
     <th>Machine Name</th>
     <th >Rate Type</th>
     <th >Rate Unit</th>
     <th >Rate</th>
     <th >Start Time</th>
     <th >End Time</th>
     <th >Total Time</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH23GH5477</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
          <div class="input-group"><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this.value)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH2398</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
         <div class="input-group" ><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this.value)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript function:

```
function calculate_time(time)
{
   var endtime1 = time;
   var starttime1= 
   $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find("input[name=start_time]")val();
   alert(starttime1);
   alert(endtime1);
}
```

Getting error :

> start time undefined

I am new to js.

Comment: You are missing a dot after find

Comment: Thank you all for replying.. but still i am getting same error.Table that i am using is datatable.

Comment: can you defelop a jsfiddle so that i can test it. It is difficult to reconstruct a problem which depends on third party tools like jquery and datepickers

Answer (score 1):

Since you are you are using the reference of the current element inside the function, first pass `this` instead of `this.value` in the function. You also missed dot (`.`) before `val()`.

Now change the function like the following:

```
function calculate_time(time){
  var endtime1 = time.value;
  var starttime1= $(time).closest('td').prev('td').find('.start_time').val();
  alert(starttime1);
  alert(endtime1);
}
```

```js
function calculate_time(time){
   var endtime1 = time.value;
   var starttime1= $(time).closest('td').prev('td').find('.start_time').val();
   alert(starttime1);
   alert(endtime1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example1" class="machinetable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>

     <th>Sr. no.</th>
     <th>Machine Name</th>
     <th >Rate Type</th>
     <th >Rate Unit</th>
     <th >Rate</th>
     <th >Start Time</th>
     <th >End Time</th>
     <th >Total Time</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH23GH5477</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
          <div class="input-group"><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH2398</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
         <div class="input-group" ><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in you code:

1. You can pass the reference of the element in the `calculate_time()` function so that you can use that element to find other elements nearby it. Currently `$(this)` inside `calculate_time()` is referencing the `Window` object and not your actual element.
2. Use `$(elem).closest('td').prev('td').find("input[name=start_time]").val()` after you pass the element reference in the `calculate_time()` function.

Below is the working example to get the value of `start_time` and `end_time` you still need to integrate this with your date fields and calculate the difference after you get the date value by using the code below:

```js
function calculate_time(elem)
{
   var endtime1 = elem.value;
   var starttime1 = $(elem).closest('td').prev('td').find("input[name=start_time]").val();
   alert(starttime1);
   alert(endtime1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example1" class="machinetable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>

     <th>Sr. no.</th>
     <th>Machine Name</th>
     <th >Rate Type</th>
     <th >Rate Unit</th>
     <th >Rate</th>
     <th >Start Time</th>
     <th >End Time</th>
     <th >Total Time</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH23GH5477</td>
      <td>per Hover</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
          <div class="input-group"><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH2398</td>
      <td>per Hover</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
         <div class="input-group" ><input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" ><input name="end_time" value="" onchange="calculate_time(this)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass one more param when calling a function like this onchange="calculate_time(this.value, '1')"
 where 1 is id of start_time
like below

```
<input name="start_time" id="start_time1" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text">
```

then your function look like:

```
<script>
function calculate_time(time, id)
{
//alert(id);
   var endtime1 = time;
   var starttime1= $("#start_time"+id).val();

   alert(endtime1);
   alert(starttime1);
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
no validation done here.

```html
  <table id="example1" class="machinetable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>

     <th>Sr. no.</th>
     <th>Machine Name</th>
     <th >Rate Type</th>
     <th >Rate Unit</th>
     <th >Rate</th>
     <th >Start Time</th>
     <th >End Time</th>
     <th >Total Time</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH23GH5477</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
          <div class="input-group">
          
          <input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text" id="time_a_1">
          
          <span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" >
            <input name="end_time" value="" onkeyup="calculate_time(1)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text" id="time_a_2">
            <span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time" id="time_a"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>JCB</td>
      <td>MH2398</td>
      <td>per Hour</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>
         <div class="input-group" >
         <input name="start_time" value="" class="form-control form-cont datetime start_time" type="text" id="time_b_1">
         <span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-group nomargin">
            <div class="input-group" >
            <input name="end_time" value="" onkeyup="calculate_time(2)" class="form-control form-cont datetime end_time" type="text" id="time_b_2">
            <span class="input-group-addon group-addon"><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span></div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_time" id="time_b"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

<script>
function calculate_time(time)
{
if(time == 1){
start_time = document.getElementById("time_a_1").value
end_time = document.getElementById("time_a_2").value
total = start_time + end_time
document.getElementById("time_a").innerText = total;
}
else if(time == 2){
start_time = document.getElementById("time_b_1").value
end_time = document.getElementById("time_b_2").value
total = start_time + end_time
document.getElementById("time_b").innerText = total;
}
}
</script>
```